# Fetching the name of the APIs or Proxy in WSO2 Integration Studio

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb, wso2-integration-studio

I want to fetch the name of the Proxy or APIs in WSO2 Integration Studio and store it in Property mediator so that they can be printed in the custom Error Sequences and Templates. Are there How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get proxy name, use `expression="get-property('proxy.name')"`, and for API you can use `expression="get-property('SYNAPSE_REST_API')"`

There is one more, "uniwersal property" like `expression="get-property('ARTIFACT_NAME')"`. It gives you concatenation of type `proxy` or `api` and the artifact name, for example: *proxySampleMyService* or *apiexample*

Comment: Thanks. And how can I fetch the name of the Sequence?

Comment: Hi, unfortunately it is not possible to obtain the sequence name in the mediation in that way.